# App crashes after change to iOS6 - ucol_getVersion

Tags: ios, crash, ios6, crash-reports

I've an issue with an updated ios-app.
Last wednesday (before the iphone-keynote) the app was submitted for review.
Tested against iOS6-beta, iOS5, iOS4. -> no problems.
Compiled against iOS5 SDK

Now, I get a lot of crash-reports (system: bugsense), iOS6 only.

short-version:

**SIGSEGV
CLASS: SIGNAL    FILE: ucol_getVersion +**

After symbolication the crash-report is still not-readable:

```
- 0 libicucore.A.dylib 0x318e4570 ucol_getVersion + -1
- 1 TextInput 0x36ee7fa9 _ZN2KB8WordTrie4loadERKNS_6StringE + 280
- 2 TextInput 0x36ee1495 + 16
- 3 TextInput 0x3724bcb3 + 58
- 4 TextInput 0x3724bc51 + 44
- 5 TextInput 0x36ed8f6d _ZN14TIInputManager17load_dictionariesERKN2KB6StringES3_b + 24
- 6 TextInput 0x36ee9fc1 + 220
- 7 TextInput 0x36ee9c07 + 502
- 8 UIKit 0x32c08f7f + 162
- 9 UIKit 0x32c07fd3 + 402
- 10 UIKit 0x32c07be7 + 378
- 11 UIKit 0x32c064b9 + 464
- 12 UIKit 0x32c061ab + 150
- 13 UIKit 0x32c68975 + 388
- 14 UIKit 0x32c65845 + 528
- 15 UIKit 0x32c65541 + 104
- 16 UIKit 0x32c63f47 + 406
- 17 UIKit 0x32c63d6f + 30
- 18 UIKit 0x32c636af + 34
- 19 APP 0x000186ff 0x1000 + 95999
- 20 APP 0x00093a93 0x1000 + 600723
- 21 Foundation 0x33ac7ef5 + 16
- 22 Foundation 0x33a079f1 + 200
- 23 Foundation 0x33a0790d + 60
- 24 CFNetwork 0x388ff5df + 26
- 25 CFNetwork 0x388feccb + 54
- 26 CFNetwork 0x38927133 + 18
- 27 CoreFoundation 0x361f974d CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
- 28 CFNetwork 0x38927593 + 74
- 29 CFNetwork 0x3888b15d + 188
- 30 CoreFoundation 0x36288683 + 14
- 31 CoreFoundation 0x36287ee9 + 212
- 32 CoreFoundation 0x36286cb7 + 646
- 33 CoreFoundation 0x361f9ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
- 34 CoreFoundation 0x361f9d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
- 35 Foundation 0x339f678f + 254
- 36 APP 0x0007e4c9 0x1000 + 513225
- 37 Foundation 0x33a923db + 102
- 38 libdispatch.dylib 0x3535611f + 10
- 39 libdispatch.dylib 0x3535a961 + 252
- 40 libdispatch.dylib 0x3535aac1 + 84
- 41 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3605ea11 + 360
```

Is there someone with the same problem?
How can I locate the crash?

Comment: The stack trace is, well, less than helpful unless you're lucky and someone has had the exact same crash. You can't reproduce the crash using IOS6 RTM or the emulator yourself?

Comment: i've tested the version from App-Store without crashes on severeal iOS6 devices. I'v tested the version in simulator too. Same result.

Comment: I have similar crash: iOS 6.0 (production version, not GM seed) with cellular network . crash when trying to show an UIAlertView . Wi-Fi connection has no problem .

Answer (score 36):

I had the same problem. For me, the app was crashing when I attempted to show a UIAlertView.

Turns out that all UI-related drawing functions need to be done on the UI thread (I already knew this, I guess I was just a little sloppy). Too bad the error message is cryptic.

This thread might be helpful to you:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/728324

Given that there are UIKit classes in the stacktrace you posted, I'm guessing this is your problem too.

Comment: Had same problem. Workded for me. I just used `- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait;`

Comment: Yes, me too. I had some fetching in a background thread which was presenting an UIAlert. Using @solgar 's solution worked for me either.

Comment: same problem; solution was to move my UIAlertView code from viewWillAppear: to viewDidAppear:

Comment: i had a same problem,it worked for me by adding(performing) the method on mainthread which shows UIAlertview

Comment: Cheers, had the same problem after I switched my code to implement MBProgressHUD (which performs on backgroundthread), I added my UIAlertView in the block dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

Answer (score 9):

this issue is quite simple to fix. Here just enter your code inbetween this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// Create and show your alert view here      
});
```

Alex

Comment: this is the solution that I need