# io6 Application Crash when web service calling

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, web-services

Here I have getting Error like this:
My code works on ios 4/5 but crash on ios6.0
After these line my application has going to crash

self.con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:rq delegate:self]
        if (self.con) {

NSLog(@"connection for CON")
        myWebData = [[NSMutableData data] retain]
    }

```
    ========================================
This method not calling 
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

and here below crash log have you see:

        libicucore.A.dylib`ucol_getVersion:
        0x30f92570:  ldr.w  r2, [r0, #204]
        0x30f92574:  cbnz   r2, 0x30f925ae            ; ucol_getVersion + 62
        0x30f92576:  ldr    r2, [r0, #36]
        0x30f92578:  movs   r3, #56
        0x30f9257a:  ldrb.w r2, [r2, #68]
        0x30f9257e:  orr.w  r3, r3, r2, lsr #2
        0x30f92582:  lsls   r2, r2, #6
        0x30f92584:  strb   r3, [r1]
        0x30f92586:  strb   r2, [r1, #1]
        0x30f92588:  ldr    r2, [r0, #36]
        0x30f9258a:  ldrb.w r2, [r2, #69]
        0x30f9258e:  strb   r2, [r1, #2]
        0x30f92590:  ldr    r0, [r0, #32]
        0x30f92592:  cbz    r0, 0x30f925a8            ; ucol_getVersion + 56
        0x30f92594:  ldr    r2, [r0, #36]
        0x30f92596:  ldrb.w r0, [r2, #72]
        0x30f9259a:  ldrb.w r2, [r2, #73]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it with Xcode Version 4.5.1 (4G1004) and Deployment target 6.0 and no crash here.

Could you provide more informations about your environment ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar crash while i was exporting songs from iPod media library and was showing the alertview when exporting done. And I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12531275/662096) answer helpful.

> Actually moral of the story is that any UI rendering task should be
>   done on MainThread if you are doing multithreading.

I hope this helps.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12525857/662096)